Function does not run when calling `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange();`
I want to get the strings in a range Range(12,3,1,4), then strip the last characters of the strings, put the last characters into an array sol[], the rest I put in another array abcd[]. I then put the values ​​of these arrays into the ranges Range(1,3,1,4) and Range(2,3,1,4). I wrote the following code to try:
function getStringDSabcs(){
  var sol = [];
  var abcd = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("tests");

  const numbers2D = sh.getRange(12,3,1,4).getValues();

  const numbers1D = numbers2D.reduce((acc, row) => {
  return acc.concat(row);
}, []);
console.log(numbers1D); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

numbers1D.forEach(function(number) {
  console.log(number); // In ra từng số trong mảng
  var lastChar = number.charAt(number.length - 1); 
  var firstPart = number.substring(0, number.length - 1); 
  console.log("Phần đầu mỗi chuỗi là: "+firstPart+" và phần cuối là: "+lastChar);
  sol.push(lastChar);
  abcd.push(firstPart);
  console.log(sol); 
  console.log(abcd);

});
}

This function works very well.
Now I add the rest
sh.getRange(1,3,1,4).setValues([abcd]);
sh.getRange(2,3,1,4).setValues([sol]);

Tức là mã của tôi là
function getStringDSabcs(){
  var sol = [];
  var abcd = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("tests");

  const numbers2D = sh.getRange(12,3,1,4).getValues();

  const numbers1D = numbers2D.reduce((acc, row) => {
  return acc.concat(row);
}, []);
console.log(numbers1D); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

numbers1D.forEach(function(number) {
  console.log(number); // In ra từng số trong mảng
  var lastChar = number.charAt(number.length - 1); 
  var firstPart = number.substring(0, number.length - 1); 
  console.log("Phần đầu mỗi chuỗi là: "+firstPart+" và phần cuối là: "+lastChar);
  sol.push(lastChar);
  abcd.push(firstPart);
  console.log(sol); 
  console.log(abcd);
sh.getRange(1,3,1,4).setValues([abcd]);
sh.getRange(2,3,1,4).setValues([sol]);

});
}

This new function doesn't work: The execution log still says it started and finished, but the start and end are only 1 second apart. Also console.log and return values ​​are not present.
I have checked the code very carefully but don't know where the error occurred.
I saw somewhere an article about Function does not run when calling SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange();.

try:
function getStringDSabcs(){
  var sol = [];
  var abcd = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("tests");

  const numbers2D = sh.getRange(12, 3, 1, 4).getValues();
  const numbers1D = numbers2D[0];  // Since you are getting a 1x4 range, numbers1D is just the first row

  numbers1D.forEach(function(number) {
    console.log(number); // Log each number in the array
    var lastChar = number.charAt(number.length - 1); 
    var firstPart = number.substring(0, number.length - 1); 
    console.log("Phần đầu mỗi chuỗi là: " + firstPart + " và phần cuối là: " + lastChar);
    sol.push(lastChar);
    abcd.push(firstPart);
  });

  console.log("Final sol array:", sol); 
  console.log("Final abcd array:", abcd);

  sh.getRange(1, 3, 1, 4).setValues([abcd]);
  sh.getRange(2, 3, 1, 4).setValues([sol]);
}


Thank you for your help, it ran great. However, let me ask, why does App Script not report an error in my situation? And when I delete the 2 new lines of code, the function still doesn't run?

@LêPhongNguyễn your script has an issue because you're trying to update the spreadsheet inside the forEach loop. this could lead to multiple calls to sh.getRange().setValues(), causing the script to behave unexpectedly and potentially fail silently

To avoid errors like this, what should I do?
